# I could not use spacing inside the node

Tags: line-spacing

How do I use \ begin {spacing} {1} \ textbf {About Courses}} \ end {spacing} within a node?

```
\documentclass[margin=10pt]{standalone}
\PassOptionsToPackage{usenames,svgnames}{xcolor}
\usepackage[ngerman]{babel}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{microtype,setspace}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{mindmap}
\begin{document}
\pagecolor{black!50!green!50!}
\begin{tikzpicture}[
             nodes = { font = \sffamily\bfseries, align = center,
                       execute at begin node = {\hspace{0pt}}},
      large/.style = { concept, font = \Large\sffamily\bfseries},
       huge/.style = { concept, font = \Huge\sffamily\bfseries},
      black/.style = { color = black},
      white/.style = { color = white},
    black45/.style = { color = black, sibling angle = 45},
    white40/.style = { color = white, sibling angle = 40},
  ]
  \path[mindmap, concept color = purple!30!yellow!70!, text = white]
    node[huge, scale = 0.85, text = purple] {Manual}
    [clockwise from = -60]
    child[concept color = blue] {
        node[large, level distance = 2.4cm] {\textbf{\fontsize{3mm}{3mm}\selectfont About Courses}}};

\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You only need to add a key like `align=center`.

```
\documentclass[margin=10pt]{standalone}
\PassOptionsToPackage{usenames,svgnames}{xcolor}
\usepackage[ngerman]{babel}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{microtype,setspace}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{mindmap}
\begin{document}
\pagecolor{black!50!green!50!}
\begin{tikzpicture}[
             nodes = { font = \sffamily\bfseries, align = center,
                       execute at begin node = {\hspace{0pt}}},
      large/.style = { concept, font = \Large\sffamily\bfseries},
       huge/.style = { concept, font = \Huge\sffamily\bfseries},
      black/.style = { color = black},
      white/.style = { color = white},
    black45/.style = { color = black, sibling angle = 45},
    white40/.style = { color = white, sibling angle = 40},
  ]
  \path[mindmap, concept color = purple!30!yellow!70!, text = white]
    node[huge, scale = 0.85, text = purple] {Manual}
    [clockwise from = -60]
    child[concept color = blue] {
        node[large, level distance = 2.4cm,align=center] {
         \begin{spacing}{1} \textbf{About Courses} \end{spacing}
        %\textbf{\fontsize{3mm}{3mm}\selectfont About Courses}
        }};

\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]