# How to use package setspace whit package hyperref, like this: \ node {\ href {https://google.com} {\ begin {spacing} {2} Text \ end {spacing}}}?

Tags: tikz-pgf, hyperref, nodes, setspace

How to use package setspace whit package hyperref. because I've been getting the following error below when I try to generate the tex file described in my MWE:

**! Missing \endgroup inserted.
 
\endgroup 
l.5 ...google.com}{\begin{spacing}{2} \end{spacing}}
                                                  };**

Here my MWE:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{hyperref,setspace,tikz}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\draw node {\href{https://google.com}{\begin{spacing}{2} \end{spacing}}}; 
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Re-written like this, there are no problems:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{hyperref,setspace,tikz}
\begin{document}
    \href{https://google.com}{\begin{spacing}{2} Line1 \linebreak Line2 \end{spacing}}
\end{document}
```

But I got the same error rewriting like this:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{hyperref,setspace,tikz}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
    \href{https://google.com}{\begin{spacing}{2} Line1 \linebreak Line2 \end{spacing}}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Note: I've already tried using the align = center key advised by @marmot when answering an earlier question of my own. See:[I could not use spacing inside the node](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/476818/178949)

Comment: The first thing one may try out before putting something in a node is whether it works outside of a node. Just putting `\href{https://google.com}{\begin{spacing}{2} \end{spacing}}` produces `! pdfTeX error (ext1): \pdfendlink cannot be used in vertical mode.
\close@pdflink ...\Hy@VerboseLinkStop \pdfendlink 
                                                  
l.4 ...ogle.com}{\begin{spacing}{2} \end{spacing}}` so I suggest you first try to invent something that works outside Ti*k*Z before trying to embed it in a node.

Comment: Hi @marmot, I rewrote the tex file and generated the pdf without problems, thus (without the preamble): \ begin {document}
\ href {https://google.com} {\ begin {spacing} {2} Line1 \ linebreak Line2 \ end {spacing}}
\ end {document}. But I got the same error rewriting like this (without the preamble): \ begin {tikzpicture}
\ href {https://google.com} {\ begin {spacing} {2} Line1 \ linebreak Line2 \ end {spacing}}
\ end {tikzpicture}.

Comment: I cannot compile the document you refer to as working with `pdflatex`, but `xelatex` works. And with `xelatex` also `\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{hyperref,setspace,tikz}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\draw node[text width=4cm] {\href{https://google.com}{\begin{spacing}{2} Line1 \linebreak Line2 \end{spacing}}}; 
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}` works, so I can put it into a node.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As @marmot verified and following your guidelines I changed engine. I am using the command: latexmk -pdflua -pvc file.tex and really, with xelatex worked, i used latexmk -pvc -pdfxe, thanks for the warning.